# Copy/Paste element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, canvas, copy-paste

I have a `div` that I'm appending to another `div` when a button is clicked. I'm also calling a bunch of functions on the `div` that gets created.

HTML

```
<a onClick="drawRect();">Rect</a>
```

JS

```
function drawRect(){
    var elemRect = document.createElement('div');
    elemRect.className = 'elem elemRect';
    elemRect.style.position = "absolute";
    elemRect.style.background = "#ecf0f1";
    elemRect.style.width = "100%";
    elemRect.style.height = "100%";
    elemRect.style.opacity = "100";

    renderUIObject(elemRect);

    $('.elemContainer').draggableParent();

    $('.elemContainer').resizableParent();

    makeDeselectable();

    handleDblClick();
}



var createDefaultElement = function() {
    ..
    ..
};

var handleDblClick = function() {
    ..
    ..
};

var renderUIObject = function(object) {
    ..
    ..
};

var makeDeselectable = function() {
    ..
    ..
};
```

I could clone the element when the browser detects a keydown event

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 77) { 
    $('.ui-selected').clone();
    return false;
  }
});
```

then append it to #canvas. But the problem is, none of the functions I mentioned above get called with this method.

How can I copy/paste an element (by pressing CMD+C then CMD+V) and call those above functions on the cloned element?

Comment: show how you are trying to call those functions

Comment: I edited the question to include that.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery.clone method returns the cloned node. So you could adjust your code to do something like this:

```
var myNodes = $('.ui-selected').clone();
myNodes.each(function () {
    createDefaultElement(this);
    appendResizeHandles(this);
    appendOutline(this);
});
```